# Jquery: highlight rows printed in .html() response

Tags: html, jquery

I'm having a couple of issue with Jquery. Basically I have a .html() response printed and I have to highlight rows of a table on mouseover but it doesn't work.

**HTML table**

```
<table id='simplehighlight'>
<tr>
 <td>header 1</td>
 <td>header 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>bla bla bla</td>
 <td>highlight this row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>bla bla bla</td>
 <td>or highlight this row</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the table above is printed with PHP echos. The PHP script is called with ajax and the response is printed inside a div with the .html() function. Example:

```
function(data, textStatus) {
          if(textStatus == "success") {
             $('#resultBox').html(data);
          }
        }, 'text/html');
}
```

*data* is the **HTML table**. Last but not least I have the jquery code for active the highlight which it doesn't work.

```
    $("simplehighlight tr").not(':first').hover(
       function () {
                    $(this).css("background","yellow");
       },
       function () {
                    $(this).css("background","");
       }
    );
```

instead of highlighting the row I have put a simple *alert* to check if it works, but obviusly it does not. Why? What's wrong in my code? How can I accomplish my task, aka highlight these rows?

Thanks everyone,
Alberto-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching an event handler via jQuery's `on` should work:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#simplehighlight tr:not(:first-child)', function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'highlighted' );
} );
```

### See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EEXkj/6/).

The good thing with using `on` this way is, that the table you mentioned may be added at any time (e.g. through an AJAX call). When calling `on` directly on the jQuery match (as in `jQuery("#simplehighlight tr").not(':first').on(...)`), jQuery binds the handler only to the currently **existing** DOM elements.

Note: I replaced the `hover` event with `mouseenter mouseleave`, because `hover` is removed since jQuery 1.9:

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave".

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that commands such as the one your are trying to execute, will only be executed against elements that **already exist** in your DOM. So basically you have to combine the two segments of your code like this:

```
    function(data, textStatus) {
      if(textStatus == "success") {
        $('#resultBox').html(data);

        $("simplehighlight tr").not(':first').hover(
            // do highlight stuffs here
            alert("IT WORKS??");
        });
      }
    }, 'text/html');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing the `hover()` function manually, you should set up an event handler to do so. Events will also get captured from inserted elements; so you may set up the event listener even before the AJAX call.

```
jQuery( 'simplehighlight tr' ).not(':first').on( 'hover', function() {
    var currentTR = jQuery( this );
    currentTR.addClass( 'highlight' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery("#simplehighlight tr").not(':first').mouseover(function(){
    // do highlight stuffs here
    alert("IT WORKS??");
});
```

here a js fiddle
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/animesh/WXgVr/)